# NumPy: Need a function where: f(target array, array of indicies, some number) -> target array with indicies filled in with some number

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am banging my head against the wall trying to solve this problem.

Here is an example:

```
A = [[3, 1, 2], 
     [1, 4, 3], 
     [8, 9, 6]] (the target array)

B = [[0], 
     [1], 
     [1]] (the array of indicies)

aNumber = 1.2222 (some number)
```

I am trying to do a vectorized approach with this result:

```
A = [[1.2222, 1, 2],
     [1, 1.2222, 3], 
     [8, 1.2222, 6]]
```

Its taking in A, going to the index referenced by B and replacing it with aNumber.

Obviously this is incorrect: A[B] = aNumber ... but it represents the vectorized approach of what im trying to accomplished

Yes, I can achieve this with a for loop, but is there an array broadcast way of doing this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to supply indices for both axes:

```
A[np.arange(len(A)), B.flat] = aNumber
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me! Can you help me why this wouldn't work: A[:, B.flat] = aNumber   ?

Comment: @Moose - The syntax `A[:, [0,1,1]]` selects whole columns; the first column and two times the second column. You can't use it to set a single value per row. Your way also makes sense, but that's just not how the numpy designers implemented it :)